# split the merged rows in csv file thorugh powershell

Tags: powershell

I have exported to csv file using powershell command .I got output like below

```
Location   IP                     Name
 east      System.Object[]        System.Object[]
 wast      System.Object[]        System.Object[]
```

To remove System.Object I used -join ', ' for IP and Name in my powershell scripts. Then I gotoutput with rows merged like below

```
Location   IP                     Name
   east      1,2,3,4,5            a,b,c,d,e,f
   west      6,7,8,9,             x,y,z,q
```

Below is my script .Please suggest any changes to not to get merged rows.

```
$report= @()
   $list = "first", "second", "third"
   Foreach($i in $list)
   location = $i.location
   IP =($i.IP -join ',')
   Name= ($i.Name -join ',')
   $report | Format-table Location,IP,Name
   $report |Export-Csv sample.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple apporach...
Considering that `$list` is an object contains the Location,IP and Name properties with data in it.

```
$report= @()
$list = "first", "second", "third"

foreach($i in $list) 
{
    $row = "" | Select location,IP,Name
    $row.location = $i.location
    $row.IP =($i.IP -join ',')
    $row.Name= ($i.Name -join ',')
    $report += $row
}

$report | Export-Csv sample.csv
```

Comment: @avshalon I used ur script still am getting merged rows.

Comment: Please find the two rows of orginal input below

@{Location=SouthCentral; Name =PPA,PPX,PPD; IP=10.10.x.x, 10.10.x.x, 10.10.x.xf}
@{Location=EastCentral; Name =PPZ,PBZ; IP=10.10.x.x, 10.10.x.x}

Answer (score 0):

You really need to show us what this input really looks like (where it came from), since System.Object[]is a collection and must be expanded in order to be used. Sanitized of course. Do, not use Format-* in this code, that is not needed for your end goal. CSV file type is a table by design, so, forcing the table is redundant and really only needed if you are doing screen output. [Use a PSCustomObject/Hashtable instead.](https://powershellexplained.com/2016-10-28-powershell-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-pscustomobject/)

For example:

```
'D:\Temp\LocationRaw.csv' | 
 ForEach{
 $ReportObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
        Location = $PSItem.location
        IP       = $PSItem.IP
        Name     = $PSItem.Name
    }  | Export-Csv 'D:\Temp\LocationFinal.csv' -Append
 }
```

Of course, I am making assumptions here since I've no idea what this data really looks like, mean how those collections are shown. If they are collection, then we are potentially talking...

```
($PSItem).location
```

Or

```
$PSItem | Select-Object -ExpandProperty location
```

... then working with that expended data.

Comment: The input comes from resource group of Azure for collecting the data about load balancer. From Different resources(location), and each resource have  no of load balancers (Name ) and there is an IPaddress(IP) for each.

Comment: AM able to export csv file with all these values.But the problem am facing is  " All the names under one location comes in same row of different column (i.e Name) and all the IP's for those names comes under same row of different column(i.e IP). I need to get each name in each row and corresponding IP also in each row, eventhough they belong to same location.
I tried your code its showing my error like "The string argument contains a character that is not valid.Correct the argument an then try the operation again.